# Calculate Multiple Yii2 Mask Input with Multiple ID

Tags: javascript, yii2

Halo, I am using yii2 mask input, and I am confuse how to calculate multiple input with multiple id.

This is my inputs :

```
<tr>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'tinggal')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),
        [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator' => '.',
                'digits' => 0,
                'autoGroup' => true,
                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                'rightAlign' => false,                                                                  
            ],
            'options' => [
                'id' => 'tinggal',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'maxlength' => true,
            ]
        ])
    ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'bb_tinggal')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),
        [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'alias' => 'numeric',
                'groupSeparator' => '.',
                'digits' => 0,
                'autoGroup' => true,
                'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
                'rightAlign' => false,                                                                  
            ],
            'options' => [
                'id' => 'bb_tinggal',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'maxlength' => true,
            ]                                                               
        ])
    ?>
</tr>
```

At usual, I use this js for input without mask :

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#tinggal, #bb_tinggal", function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("#tinggal, #bb_tinggal").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();
    });
    $("#jlh_uang_masuk_berangkat").val(sum);
});
```

I also try unmask the inputs with this code :

```
var tinggal_asli = $("#tinggal").val();
var tinggal = tinggal_asli.replace(/,/g , "");
```

but I dont know how to include it into my js code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do with my code and its working.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#tinggal, #bb_tinggal", function() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("#tinggal, #bb_tinggal").each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val().replace(/,/g , "");
    });
    $("#jlh_uang_masuk_berangkat").val(sum);
});
```

If anyone have better answer, please answer.